Efficient interactive plots of large datasets -- which framework to use?
I have a moderate-to-large dataset of ~500k points which I would to visualize with an interactive 2d scatterplot (ideally through a web-app).
Usually am quite fond of  the altair package (Python) for interactive plotting. Unfortunately this solution does not scale well to this dataset size (not even with vegafusion). The results are always very sluggish.
To anyone experienced -- which framework would you recommend in such a case?
I know that subsampling or rendering parts of the data as a static image would be an option, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Perhaps consider binning your data into max 50k groups (or less) and then have some drill-down or filter functionality. I would avoid having 500k points on a single scatterplot.

While there are exciting experimental efforts to GPU accelerate rendering of Vega (Altair) visualizations, none of them are ready for production use at the moment. The most performant solution in Altair atm would probably be to use Vegafusion directly and use something like Zoom-based rasterization/aggregation as in this example rendering 10 million data points.
Alternatives outside the Vega/Altair ecosystem include datashader which performs more sophisticated rasterization/aggregation together with additional optimizations, and the WebGL offerings in Bokeh, Plotly, and jupyter-scatter.
